# Orchard ContentItem's AutoroutePart DisplayUrl

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have a custom content type built through the UI (e.g. not via a module) that has a couple of fields on it, one of which is a ContentItemPicker. I managed to get everything with the front-end working for this with the exception of finding the friendly URL off of the ContentItem from the Model's collection of items. I'm seeing some examples where I'm supposed to use `Url.ImageDisplayUrl([ContentItem])`, but that gives me this error: `'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' has no applicable method named 'ItemDisplayUrl' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.`

My using statements at the top are as follows:

```
@using Orchard.ContentPicker.Fields
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@using System.Linq
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@using Orchard.Mvc.Html;
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
```

I'd assume I'm missing something with those, but can't seem to figure out what. The way I'm building out my view is below, and the URL I am trying to get is off of `tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.NavigationItem`:

```
/** @Model.Items is a collection of my custom content types that were created through the UI **/
foreach (var tab in @Model.Items)
{
    var t = new SliderTab
    {
        DisplayOrder = tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.DisplayOrder.Value,
        ButtonText = tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.ButtonText.Value,
        Description = tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.Description.Value,
        ImageUrl = tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.Image.Url,
        Title = tab.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title,
        ContentItem = tab.ContentItem,
        TabText = tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.TabText.Value
    };

    /** HomepageTab is the custom content type created in the Orchard UI which has a ContentPickerField associated with it. The name on that is NavigationItem, so I just need the friendly URL off of a ContentPickerField's associated ContentItem **/
    if (tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.NavigationItem != null && tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.NavigationItem.Ids != null)
    {
        //this is way, super hacky - getting the actual friendly URL would be better
        t.NavigateUrl = "/Contents/Item/Display/" + tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.NavigationItem.Ids[0];
    }

    tabs.Add(t);
}
```

** **Edit** **

I have a class declaration for HomepageTab at the top which does not correlate to the `tab.ContentItem.HomepageTag` as that is dynamic off the ContentItem property. It is structured like this:

```
public class HomepageTab
{
    public dynamic DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ButtonText { get; set; }
    public dynamic ContentItem { get; set; }
    public string TabText { get; set; }
    public string NavigateUrl { get; set; }
    public string TabId
    {
        get { return "t" + this.DisplayOrder.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you try to do `foreach (IContent tab in @Model.Items)`? That should make the type explicit for the compiler, which will then be able to infer what extension method to use.

Comment: I tried that, but it kicked back with `'Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem' does not contain a definition for 'HomepageTab' and no extension method 'HomepageTab' accepting a first argument of type 'Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem' could be found`

Comment: `tab.As<HomePageTab>()`

Comment: I updated the question to show my class declaration for `HomepageTab` which is where `var t = new HomepageTab [...]` is coming into play. Since my naming scheme is a little confusing in this context, when I do the above, I am getting a different error which I'm assuming is just my lack of understanding of Orchard. The error is: `The type 'ProjectionWidget_url_homepage_cshtml.HomepageTab' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentExtensions.As<T>(Orchard.ContentManagement.IContent)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from [...]`

Comment: Right, remove that class and instead of `tab.ContentItem.HomePageTab`, try `tab.As<HomePageTab>()`. Provided `HomePageTab` is the type of your part.

Comment: I tried that, but still the same error. I still need that POCO for some other stuff I'm doing (specifically that `TabId` property), so I just renamed it to `SliderTab` instead of having it be the same name, but it still failed with that `The type or namespace name 'HomepageTab' could not be found.` error. Even going back to using `var` instead of `IContent` didn't work and still threw that same error.

Comment: What is the type name of the content part?

Comment: It's `HomepageTab`. When I go from `IContent` to `var`, it works. It just doesn't like `IContent` for some reason.

Comment: Did you include the necessary `@using` statement pointing at the namespace where that part is defined? Did you use `As` like I suggested above? What exactly works now?

Comment: The part is just a custom content type I added through the UI - there isn't any backend code for it. If I change `IContent` to `var`, convert everything to the class above (defined in the view itself) then it all works, but the URL points to /Content/Display/[Id] as opposed to the AutoroutePart URL which is much friendlier. So, it works if I revert back to the original code as pasted in the question, but I'm trying to get the AutoroutePart off the associated ContentItem from my custom type.

Comment: OK, that explains why `As` can't work then. So `Model.Items` is the collection of items from the content item field, right? If you cast each of those into `IContent`, you should be able to pass it to `Url.ItemDisplayUrl`. No need to access `AutoroutePart`.

Comment: Sure feels closer, but not quite there. If you look at the loop statement above, I changed where it sets `NavigateUrl` to this: `t.NavigateUrl = tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.NavigationItem.ContentItem.As<IContent>().ItemDisplayUrl;`, but that is failing. I tried it with and without the `ContentItem` property on there, but the error is `'Orchard.ContentPicker.Fields.ContentPickerField' does not contain a definition for 'ContentItem'`. The property `HomepageTab` is my custom type off of the UI and `NavigationItem` is the Id of the property for the ContentPickerField. So close!

Comment: What you tried does not seem to make sense and this is getting unnecessarily confusing. Let's restart this on saner bases: please specify the names and types of everything. For instance, what is the name of the field, and what are you trying to get the url of? What template are you trying this from?

Comment: Agreed. I updated the code with some more details, including the class modifications so now that's my baseline. Essentially all I need is the friendly URL from a ContentPickerField's referenced ContentItem and it does not support selecting multiple items, so just need to pick a single one. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is much clearer. Giving you an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.NavigationItem` is your content item picker field, but expressed this way, it's a dynamic object, so the compiler can get all sorts of confused if you try to use it without casting it. So first I'd recommend casting:

```
var pickerField = tab.ContentItem.HomepageTab.NavigationItem as ContentPickerField;
if (pickerField != null) {
```

Then you can get the first and only item in the field (caution, we're likely causing a select N+1 issue here, see below):

```
    var firstItem = pickerField.ContentItems.FirstOrDefault();
```

Finally, we can ask for the display URL for that item:

```
    if (firstItem != null) {
        var url = Url.ItemDisplayUrl(firstItem);
```

This should work just fine. Be careful however: as I said above, getting the collection of items for each tab may trigger one new database query per tab, degrading performance. To avoid that problem, you could pre-fetch the related content items with a technique similar to what I describe in this post: https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/speeding-up-pages-with-lots-of-media-content-items

Instead of pre-fetching images, what you'd do here is first get a list of all the related ids (that's free, those ids come stored in the fields, which are stored with the content items you already have). Then you'd build a local cache of ids to items using a `GetMany`. And finally you'd use that cache instead of the `ContentItems` collection to look-up items from the ids.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Perfect, that worked exactly as I needed! I'm not too concerned about the N+1 issue in this instance because it's a set of homepage tabs, of which there will only ever be a max of ~6, but that's definitely good to know going forward if I do this. Thanks!!